# Mount an IP camera to the top of a flagpole

Tags: video, home-security, internet-of-things

I am trying to set up some DIY home security video streams. I have several IP cams, like the D-Link night/day wireless Cloud Cam.

The problem is that it's hard to get a good angle and it's hard to deal with multiple video streams.

My idea is to leverage a tall (30'?) flagpole. If I could mount a camera to it at the right angle I could see my entire yard/perimeter from one camera. This is perfect since I want to be able to see where my dog is in the yard to know that she's OK.

However, I don't know what hardware (mounting stuff? solar power source? etc?) I would need nor how the heck I would get to the top of the pole to install it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A package like the [**KKmoon HW0029**](https://amzn.to/2JKupxO) or the [**FREECAM C310**](http://C310) would probably do it pretty neatly.

To mount something on the poll you can use a bracket like this https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pole-Mount-Bracket-SUNLUXY-Universal-Column-Camera-Mounting-Bracket-8-inches-/282935918551

Comment: Thank you! The bracket was the real answer, but I also like that first camera you linked in terms of it's solar panel on top design.